# Canvas in foreground - html background

Tags: html, css

i need help to bring my canvas in foreground and HTML in Background but clickable html:

```
<div id="webgl">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./GPUFluid-1.3.js"></script>
        <script>IOHP2();</script> 
    </div>


    <div class="container-fluid" style="z-index: -1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4">Mytext</div>
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

the Problem is then i write code here (Mytext) i see this in the page, but the background is black and the canvas is in background (i cant see the canvas)

Please help me :)

Thank you Guys